# geometrical transformation order

Tags: geometry

I have a question about translation and reflection. If i have a triangle with points $abc$, does the order matter (translation and reflection order)? like shouldt i get the same transformation lets say to a similar figure which is only slighty shifted and is a reflection of our original triangle. Shouldnt I always be able to get that triangle regardless of if i were to translate it then reflect as if i were to reflect then translate?

Comment: Cut an equilateral triangle from a piece of paper, mark the vertices on both sides and try flipping and rotating it. Then you'll get your answer, and have some fun in the process.

Answer (score 0):

In a general case the order of transformations is important. In the following picture the red triangle is first translated by vector $\vec{AA'}$ and then reflected with respect to line $p$ (brown triangles). You get a different result if you first reflect and then translate (blue triangles).

However, there is a special case when the order of transformations is not important, when line of reflection $p$ is parallel with the vector of translation.

[image]